# Spritekit Animation not working

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make a game where the main user is animated and i converted the gif to png and took each frame and put them all into a folder. However, right now I'm simply trying to get the first frame to appear, but nothing appears. Sorry if i worded this weird my English isn't very good. 
[image]

Right now I think just the first frame, "trumpyhappy1.png" should show when I try to run it, but when I run it nothing shows up.

Comment: When posting the code, use code tags rather than posting the image... Anyways, check if your guy is off screen. Print `view.size` and a `scene.size` (you can add `guy.size` as well) and see if everything is okay. Or, like pointed in the answer below, it may happen that you are presenting the wrong scene in  your `GameViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that stumbles upon this and is still wondering why their animations are blank. I found that programmatically adding the actions would cause this before viewDidAppear got called. However, setting the animation in the scene file directly I was able to get around the blank animations

Answer (score 0):

So basically in spritekit to animate a spritenode you should be doing this

```
override func didMove() {
    let mainGuy = SKSpriteNode()

    self.addChild(mainGuy)

    // Give your size and position and everything
    // Then to animate that spriteNode with frames 

    let textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "trump")
    let frames: [SKTexture] = []

    for i in 0...textureAtlas.textureNames.count {
         var name = "trumphappy\(i).png"
         frames.append(SKTexture(named: name))
    }


   // Then to create the animation add this code

   let animation = SKAction.animate(with: frames, timePerFrame: ) // Whatever time you want your animation to spend on each frame
}
```

That should work, hope it works!

Comment: thanks for responding, but it still doesn't work. When i run it the simulator is blank and doesn't show anything.

Comment: did you add the your scene to the view controller?

Comment: try adding the images to xc assets

Comment: You forgot to actually run the animation

Comment: @RahulBir I am having the same problem where the animation does not work after I added my scene to a ViewController.  Any thoughts on why this isn't working?